# Multiple SqlCommand in one SqlConnection "unreachable code detected" because of return

Tags: sql, sql-server, return, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I have built a repository for my realtime dashboard with 1 `SqlCommand` and 1 `SqlConnection`. My intent is to add more SQL commands to my existing code.

However, the problem is the return statement inside the `SqlCommand` which disables any other `SqlCommand` afterwards.

Can anyone help me to make this code below work.

This is the full code:

```
using MVCRealtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCRealtime
{
    public class LocationInfoRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<LocationInfo> GetData()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ...", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    { 
                        connection.Open(); 
                    } 

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()
                        {
                            Names = x.GetString(0),
                            Values = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                            ValuesDouble = x.GetDouble(1)

                        }).ToList();
                }
            }

            using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT... ", connection))
            {
                command2.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command2);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                { 
                    connection.Open(); 
                }

                using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()
                    {
                        Names2 = x.GetString(0),
                        Values2 = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                        ValuesDouble2 = x.GetDouble(1)

                    }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        MyHub.Show();
    }
}
}
```

This part is what i need help with(remove return):

```
return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
             .Select(x => new LocationInfo()
                 {
                    Names = x.GetString(0),
                    Values = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                    ValuesDouble = x.GetDouble(1)
                 }).ToList();
     }
```

I just don't know how to use the

```
return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()
```

without the return

Comment: Clearly if you've already `return`ed from the first statement block, you've left the code block and can't execute the second one. If you don't want to `return`, then don't `return` until you've finished executing the code you want to run. *Why is it when I go from point A to point B and then return (go right back) to point A, I can't get to point C?*

Comment: Thats my question... I dont know how to not return the first statement. Please help by changing my code.Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I can't change your code, because it's incomplete. If you want someone to change something for you, you need to provide a [mcve] that we can compile. All I can tell you based on your current code is that it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

Comment: Please teach me on making these question and bare for my foolishness if there are any. I have edited the question.Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MVCNoob What is the requirement? To return two lists?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras I actually want to return multiple sqlCommands but if i try to use the above code, the second iteration is ignored